# Do-While, Menu Selection To Exit Working Incorrectly

Tags: python, do-while, python-3.5

So, I seem to have an issue with my Selection 4. I'd like it to return to the main menu, which can just be called by main(). The "Yes" obviously works, while entering anything other than  "Yes", or "yes", should return it to the main menu. Typing in "no" or "hhh" just quits the program as well as the "Yes"/"yes". It also displays the same "Thanks for playing" message as if it were the "Yes".I'm a beginner to Python, so bear with me here.

```
while endProgram == "Yes" or "yes":

    #Selection menu, user input to navigate.
    selection = eval(input("Your selection: "))

    #Selection 1, rules.
    if selection == 1:
        rpsRules()
        returnMain = input("\nWhen you would like to return to the Main Menu, press Enter.")
        main()

    #Selection 2, begin a match against the PC, calls againstPC module with choice as an argument.
    elif selection == 2:
        againstPC(choice)

    #Selection 3, begin a match against another player locally, calls twoPlayer module.
    elif selection == 3:
        twoPlayer()

    #Selection 4, end program, with an "Are you sure?" catch.    
    elif selection == 4:
        endProgram = input("\nAre you sure you want to quit? (Yes/No) ")
        if endProgram == "Yes" or "yes":
            print("\nThanks for playing Rock, Paper, Scissors!\nSee you next time!")
            break
        elif endProgram == "No" or "no":
            main()
        else:
            main()
    elif selection == 5:
        creatorCredits()
```

Comment: `endProgram == "Yes" or "yes"` is always true since your are checking `if "yes"`, `"yes"` is not `False`, your programm will never end.

Comment: Do you have any code in your main() function that's being called in Selection 4? If not, that could be why your program just quits afterwards.  Also, you want your IF statement to look something like this: if endProgram == "Yes" or endProgram == "yes"   In addition to that, it doesn't necessarily answer your question, but after your first IF statement that tests to see if the string is "Yes" or "yes", you could just have a single else. Whether they type "no" or "blah blah blah" doesn't matter becasue both your ELIF and ELSE do a callback to main.

Comment: You need to change `x == "a" or "b"` to `x in ("a", "b")` to have the effect you want.  Otherwise the expression will always be true, because it groups like `(x == "a") or "b"` which is obviously always going to be true.

Comment: Thanks! so, endProgram == "Yes" or endProgram == "yes" fixed the problem.

Comment: Please make sure you up-vote whatever was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
while endProgram == "Yes" or "yes"
```

Doe not mean what it says when you read it out in English; you need to modify it so it checks both values against `endProgram`, like this:

```
while endProgram == "Yes" or endProgram == "yes"
```

You can then further make it simpler by saying:

```
while endProgram.lower() == "yes"
```

You should never, ever use `eval` on user input. Not only is this dangerous and a great source of bugs, it can cause unpredictable behavior in your application.

In fact, you should put this logic in your `main()` method, where you are printing the menu:

```
def main():
    # print the menu here
    selection = input("Your selection: ")
    try:
       selection = int(selection)
    except ValueError:
       print('Please enter a valid number')
       get_user_input()
    return selection
```

Then, call it in your main while:

```
while endProgram.lower() == "yes":
    selection = main()
```

The next issue you have is with this section, it is doing the same check as your while loop; which is unnecessary.

```
elif selection == 4:
    endProgram = input("\nAre you sure you want to quit? (Yes/No) ")
    if endProgram == "Yes" or "yes":
        print("\nThanks for playing Rock, Paper, Scissors!\nSee you next time!")
        break
    elif endProgram == "No" or "no":
        main()
    else:
        main()
```

---

To clean all this up, structure your program like this:

1. Print the main menu.
2. While the option from the main menu isn't to quit, run the loop.
3. After each selection in the loop, print the main menu again.

Since your main menu function returns a valid response; you can move your exit logic there as well:

```
def main():
    # print your menu here
    selection = input('Please enter your choice: ')
    try:
       selection = int(selection)
    except ValueError:
       print('Sorry, {} is not a valid choice'.format(selection))
       main()
    if selection == 4:
       exit_check = input('Are you sure you want to exit? Type Yes: ')
       return exit_check.lower()
    if 0 < selection < 4:
       print('{} is not a valid menu item.')
       main()
    return selection
```

Now, your program's main logic loop is like this:

```
end_program = main()
while end_program != 'yes':
     if end_program == 1:
         # do stuff
         end_program = main()
     if end_program == 2:
         # do stuff
         end_program = main()
print('Thank you, for playing. Good bye!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be to change your IF statement to:

```
if endProgram == "Yes" or endProgram == "yes":
...
```